# How to expand abbrevations in text during preprocessing?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, data-cleaning, preprocessing

Im doing preprocessing on english text data. I have some domain specific abbreviations, for which i'm maintaining internal dictionary with key-value pairs. The problem i'm facing is the text has abbreviations in plural forms with and without contractions like:

- Mgr's = manager
- mgrs = manager
- mgr = manager

All 3 points to a manager. Im able to capture the plural form with contractions using a regex(r"'s") and removing the 's' but, in case of no contractions i'm creating one more entry in the dictionary with plural form of the abbreviations.

Im somehow feel this is duplication and not a clean approach. Is there any better solution to address this problem?

Any immediate help on this is much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in two steps: replace the ones with 's' first, then do the rest of them.